# Getting Hyper-V PXE boot to "fall through" to the next boot device

Tags: hyper-v, pxe

I've got an environment where machines on the network all PXE boot as their first boot option. Depending on server configuration, each machine will either PXE boot into a custom task, or will just do an ipxe `exit`, which causes the machine to proceed to the next boot device.

This works just fine on real machines. I've got windows installed on the machines and if the PXE boot process returns `exit`, the machine falls through to the next boot option, which results in Windows loading.

But on a Generation 2 Hyper-V VM, once the PXE boot returns `exit`, the boot sequence is over. The boot options that follow in the VMs boot sequence list are not tried. If the server tells the machine to PXE boot into a custom task, that works just fine. So it is just the "fall-through" to the next boot options that doesn't work.

Is this a known issue? Is there something I can configure to get the behavior I want/expect?